# Can I clone node and append to it id data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some id div with elements(classes and Ids), I need to clone it and append to my clone for exact Id data. How can I do it?

```js
window.onload = Func ();

function Func () {

var temp = document.getElementById("start");
var cl = temp.cloneNode(true);
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = "class";
div.innerHTML = "MyText";
var result = cl.getElementById("second").append(div);
alert(result.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="start">
<div id="second">
<a href="#">Link</a>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Where is your code attempt ?

Comment: show some code you have so we can help you...

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=clone+in+javascript check if you get something from here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = document.getElementById("id1").lastChild;
var clone = item.cloneNode(true);
/*Id of the element below which you want to clone*/
document.getElementById("id2").appendChild(clone);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer